# jetty 9.1.2 ssl configuration as per documentation not working

Tags: java, ssl, jetty

Using jetty 9.1.2 and the documentation in [1], I am following the steps using openssl but cannot get ssl working.

I have run the following steps are per the link:

I'm in the jetty folder, debian 7.

```
cd etc
rm keystore 

openssl genrsa -des3 -out jetty.key

openssl req -new -x509 -key jetty.key -out jetty.crt

keytool -keystore keystore -import -alias jetty -file jetty.crt -trustcacerts

openssl pkcs12 -inkey jetty.key -in jetty.crt -export -out jetty.pkcs12

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore jetty.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore


cd..
```

then as per [1] it says add this xml to jetty-https.xml but to where?

```
<New id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
  <Set name="KeyStorePath"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/etc/keystore</Set>
  <Set name="KeyStorePassword">OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4</Set>
  <Set name="KeyManagerPassword">OBF:1u2u1wml1z7s1z7a1wnl1u2g</Set>
  <Set name="TrustStorePath"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/etc/keystore</Set>
  <Set name="TrustStorePassword">OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4</Set>
</New>
```

I also added etc/jetty-https.xml to start.ini

```
java -jar start.jar
```

error:jetty-https.xml java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

is there something missing in the docs? What is the full setup to get a new jetty working on https?

[1] http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html#loading-keys-and-certificates

Comment: to help others, it turns out after some playing I dont need to use the xml specified, I just updated the jetty-ssl.xml and added this to start.ini:

etc/jetty-ssl.xml
etc/jetty-https.xml

Comment: That's good, because the InvocationTargetException tells us precisely nothing without the stack trace which you should have posted.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation also fails to mention adding the following to JETTY_HOME/start.ini:

```
# ---------------------------------------
# Module: ssl
--module=ssl

# ---------------------------------------
# Module: https
--module=https
```

...without which jetty ignores all those configurations you just hand coded/copied, whatever ;-) It also mentions that using the defaults you are creating a JSSE keystore. It's JKS.

I know that you jetty experts out there are rolling your eyes, but it's part of SSL configuration and should really be included in the "Enabling SSL" documentation, for those of us that can't read the developer's minds across the internet.